# Android Saving EditText text in a PopupWindow to a Class Member string

Tags: android

I'm trying to locally save an edittext text into a string variable I have created in another class within a PopupWindow like so:

I have an addEvent_Click method which displays a PopupWindow :

```
public void addEvent_Click(View view)
{
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) WhatsNewActivity.this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    eventPopup = new PopupWindow(inflater.inflate(R.layout.eventpopup, null, true), 480, 700, true);

    eventPopup.showAtLocation(findViewById(R.id.whatsNew_Main), Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL, 0, 0);
}
```

Now I want to save all my text fields locally to an event class via save button press in the PopupWindow like so:

```
    public void btnSaveEvent_Click(View view)
{
    final EditText nameEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.nameEditText);
    final EditText timeEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.timeEditText);
    final EditText locEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.locEditText);
    final EditText sDateEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.sDateExitText);
    final EditText eDateEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.eDateEditText);
    final EditText catEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.catEditText);

    Event newEvent = new Event();

    newEvent.eventName = nameEditText.getText().toString();
    newEvent.time = timeEditText.getText().toString();
    newEvent.location = locEditText.getText().toString();
    newEvent.startDate = sDateEditText.getText().toString();
    newEvent.endDate = eDateEditText.getText().toString();
    newEvent.category = catEditText.getText().toString();


    eventPopup.dismiss();
}
```

My problem is when I debug or run the code and it tries to execute the line:

```
        final EditText nameEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.nameEditText);
```

my program crashes throwing an IllegalStateException error: Could not execute method of the activity

Any input would be appreciated, Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing nameEditText from final to private.

Try this:

```
private EditText nameEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.nameEditText);
```